# Counting prime factors of polynomial functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Let $\Omega(n)$ denote the number of prime factors (counted with multiplicity) of a non-zero integer $n$. For $f \in \mathbb Z[X]$ non-zero, let $$m(f) = \liminf_{n \to \infty} \Omega(f(n))$$
(1) Is $m(f)$ always finite?

(2) If so, is there a bound only depending on the degree of $f$ when we restrict to polynomials $f$ so that no prime divides all values of $f$?

---

Some context:

Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions can be stated as $m(L) = 1$ for any linear function $L(X) = ax+b$ with $\text{gcd}(a,b) = 1$. (The condition is equivalent to saying that no prime divides all values of $L$.)

If we have $r$ linear functions $L_i(X) = a_iX+b_i, 1 \leq i \leq r$ so that no prime divides all values of $f(X) = \prod_{i = 1}^r L_i(X)$, the famous (open) $k$-tuple conjecture states that $m(f) = r = \text{def}(f)$.

Chen's celebrated theorem on twin (semi)primes implies that $m(f) \leq 3$ for $f(X) = X(X+2)$.

Comment: Yes, it is well-known that $m(f)$ is always finite. Many books on sieve theory will give a proof; for example Hooley's book on sieves. The best bound as far as I know for an irreducible polynomial $f$ with no fixed prime divisor is $m(f) \leq 2 \deg(f) + 1$, I believe.